# Best MySQL way to move data from table to another one with junction

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table called `members`

```
| member_id | first_name | last_name | email                      | password | phone_number | country |
|-----------|------------|-----------|----------------------------|----------|--------------|---------|
| 1         | John       | Doe       | john.doe@rambo.vid         | 123456   | 654789159    | en_US   |
| 2         | Jules      | Ferry     | jules.ferry@politician.old | 456789   |              | fr_FR   |
```

I would like to create a new table `users` and move data with user_id as junture like this :

### users

```
| user_id | first_name | last_name | email                      | password |
|---------|------------|-----------|----------------------------|----------|
| 1       | John       | Doe       | john.doe@rambo.vid         | 123456   |
| 2       | Jules      | Ferry     | jules.ferry@politician.old | 456789   |
```

### members

```
| member_id | user_id | phone_number | country |
|-----------|---------|--------------|---------|
| 1         | 1       | 654789159    | en_US   |
| 2         | 2       |              | fr_FR   |
```

What is the best way (more efficient execution) in MySQL to modify the existing database ?

Comment: Have you looked at `INSERT INTO SELECT`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Yes but, I need after to do a loop for each data row and get user_id and save user_id in members table. I do not know if there is an easier way in only one query.

Comment: Not sure why you need to loop. Can you explain another way? Why can't it be 2 insert statements?

Comment: Where do you get the `user_id` from? Is it another table? You can join them if that's the case. You can run an Update statement after you are done inserting into the users table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am thinking:

```
INSERT INTO users ( user_id, member_id, first_name, last_name, email, password)
    SELECT <user_id>, -- Wherever this needs to come from or remove if its generated.
         member_id, first_name, last_name, email, password
    FROM members;
```

Followed by:

```
UPDATE members m INNER JOIN users u
    ON m.member_id = u.member_id 
    SET m.user_id = u.user_id
```

I have added the member_id field in the users table which you don't have. If you don't have the option to do that then you can use the other identifiers to join the table.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the best way but the `user_id` is `auto_increment` and I would like to get it for each row record to save it in `users` table without adding `member_id` in this table. unfortunately, I think I will need php code to do a loop to separate each record row.

Comment: No. You shouldn't have to loop as long as you can match the original data and the new data. Some common keys and you can update using the new table.